# How to reach the exception block

Tags: php, routes, request, phpunit, symfony

So I am messing around with symfony router component and I created a small wrapper.

One thing that came up was how do I get a request to throw a 500 in unit tests? The method in question is:

```
public function processRoutes(Request $request) {

    try {
        $request->attributes->add($this->_matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));
        return call_user_func_array($request->attributes->get('callback'), array($request));
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        return new RedirectResponse('/404', 302);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new RedirectResponse('/500', 302);
    }
}
```

And the test in question is:

```
public function testFiveHundred() {
    $router = new Router();

    $router->get('/foo/{bar}', 'foo', function($request){
        return 'hello ' . $request->attributes->get('bar');
    });

    $response = $router->processRoutes(Request::create('/foo/bar', 'GET'));

    $this->assertEquals(500, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

Right now the test will fail because we are defined and the status code will be 200. Is there something special I can do to the Request object I create, to make it throw a 500?

Comment: Not sure if you got the notification for the comment in my answer. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got several options here you can play with:

1. Decide that a specific path will always throw an exception.
   This will force you to make some changes in your code.

```
public function processRoutes(Request $request) {
    ...
        if ($request->getRequestUri() == '/path/that/throws/exception') {
            throw  Exception('Forced to throw exception by URL');
        }
    ...
}

public function testFiveHundred() {
    ...
    $response = $router->processRoutes(Request::create('/path/that/throws/exception', 'GET'));
    ...
}
```

2. Make a `DummyRequest` object that will extends your original Request class and make sure this object will raise an Exception (for example - you know for sure that you use the `getPathInfo()`, so you can use this).

```
class DummyRequest extends Request {

    public function getPathInfo() {
        throw new Exception('This dummy request object should only throw an exception so we can test our routes for problems');
    }

}

public function testFiveHundred() {
    ...
    $dummyRequest = new DummyRequest();
    $response = $router->processRoutes($dummyRequest);
    ...
}
```

Since the function `getRequestUri` of our `$dummyRequest` throws an exception, your call to `$router->processRoutes` will have our dummy to throw that exception.

> This is a general idea, you would probably need to play a bit with the namespaces and the functions there (I didn't test it, however this should work).

Comment: @TheWebs, did the answer worked exactly as is? which of the two versions did you choose?

Comment: I went with the first one I had to change `Exception` to `\Exception` for it to work as intended in both the try catch and the example code.

Comment: Got it. BTW, I think you should also add testing/unittest/php-unittest for the tags in the question to make it more searchable, and if you have a few minutes to check the second option I gave it will be great.

Comment: (I didn't add any of them since I didn't know if you are using php-unittest or something)